# ember js form submit to view

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, single-page-application

With emberjs (1.0.0rc1) and ember-data (very recent build #36d3f1b), I am trying to setup a basic crud example. I can't figure out how to retrieve a submitted model from a view and then update/save it. Here is what my code looks like:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.route('create');
    this.route('edit', {
      path: '/:post_id'
    });
  });
});

App.PostsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Post.find();
  }
});

App.PostsCreateView = Ember.View.extend({
  submit: function () {
    console.log(this.get('model')); // undefined
  }
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Post.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 2,
  title: 'a',
  body: 'aa'
}, {
  id: 5,
  title: 'b',
  body: 'bb'
}];

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.create({
    simulateRemoteResponse: false
  })
});
```

and the create template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/create">
  {{#view App.PostsCreateView tagName="form" classNames="form-horizontal"}}
  <h3>Create</h3>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="title">Title</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title" />
      {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="title"}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="body">Body</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="password" id="body" placeholder="Body" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <button class="btn">Create</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>{{#linkTo 'posts'}}Back{{/linkTo}}</div>
  {{/view}}
</script>
```

How can I access the value of the form (serialized to the model) from the submit hook? Secondly, how do I then persist this via the FixtureAdapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of your question is tricky to answer because it's actually pretty simple, but in order for it to be simple you'll need to change the way you think about model CRUD. Your "submit" function is not needed. When you instantiate a view) it should have an instance of your model bound to it. (If you're creating a new one it will be a new, empty instance.) When you make changes to that model in the view, they are made instantly; no need for submit. (After all, what would you submit to?)

I'm not sure this actually answers your question, but maybe it puts you on a track to answering it.

I can be a lot more definite about your second question, persisting a value via the FixturesAdapter: you can't. The FixturesAdapter is just that, an adapter for loading fixtures (essentially read-only data) into the store. Changes made to models from the FixturesAdapter will only last until the app is reloaded. To persist data you will need to transition from the FixturesAdapter to a different adapter (probably the RestAdapter).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So following the approach you outlined, would that not cause round-trips to the server every time an attribute is modified (user types in a letter in a textbox)? For the second part, I should have been more clear; I just want to play with FixturesAdapter as if it were a real store, even though changes are lost on refresh, then swap it out for a REST adapter. Could you maybe point me to a working example?

Comment: No. I'm not an expert on the details, but the more sophisticated adapters are "smart" about when they persist updates to the server, and don't push a model every time it's touched.

Comment: For the FixturesAdapter, that's a good approach, because they give you something to develop with before you have a back-end server set up. However, in this world, "persist" means "make it last beyond refresh"; what you get by using Fixtures is the ability to put off dealing with that kind of persistence until later. If it's time for you to deal with it, it's time to move up from FixturesAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

[this article](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Ffabriciotav.org%2Fblog%2F2013%2F02%2F20%2Fconceitos-basicos-do-emberjs.html) deals with building a small example app including a creation form (it's originally in portuguese, but fortunately, google translate doesn't garble the text too much in this case).
the code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/fabriciotav/4980834) (the important part is way down the page) and a live example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/fabriciotav/raw/4980834/).